# How to check current timeout in Selenium?

Tags: testing, selenium, timeout

Is there any possibility to check current timeout? Something like getTimeout (this command does not exists, so I ask you for clue and help).
I have got a loop in my script and I need to change the timeout in each iteration (and I do it now). But I don't know if timeout is truly changed after my operations.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your selenium version. For Selenium RC, timeout is simply a for loop with Thread.sleep(1000). And the default value is to loop 30 times, so essentially it's 30 seconds. Instead of getting this value from Selenium, why don't you define your custom value for timeout and pass it to selenium and to your function?